# Verilog real stuck at wrong state

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Can anyone explain why real_OUT is not changing from 0 to 3.3 in below code?
[image]

Comment: there is a definitely a mess with the sensitivity list, but can you create a real  reproducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation in your `if ... else` statements is misleading.

The `else` statement on line 37 matches the `if` statement on line 35. So execution of your `always` block jumps from line 32 `if (EN)` to line 39 `else real_OUT=1'b0;`

Answer (score 0):

Standard error: you sensitivity list is incomplete. It is not using `AVDD, Vhist_hl, Vhist_lh`.

Do NOT use `always @( name, name, ...)` but use `always @( * )` or `always_comb`

Also your code can not be synthesized as you are using both rising and falling edges.

Comment: I started with always @(*) and saw this issue and hence changed to above format. Code is not intended for synthesis. Thaks.

Comment: This HDL looks like it's meant to simulate the behavior of an analog circuit. I don't think it could be synthesized to the intended hardware even if the sensitivity list were fixed.